# Validation on parameters to a WebAPI action

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI action in which I expect an argument to be provided to match a particular regex (or other validation attribute, say `[Range(1, 20)]`). The parameter provided also happens to be part of the URL.

```
[Route("api/stuff/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([RegularExpression(@"^\d+-[a-z]{3}$")] id) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately the model state is always valid, even when the value doesn't match the regex.

How would I do validation of this URL segment?

Comment: Can you use route constraints to restrict the parameter  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by @Pratik you can route constraints are the simplest/easiest way to go about it.

I made a Validation attribute like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class IPAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        dynamic address = validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        long? scope = address.ScopeId;

        var isValid = IPAddresses.IsValid(value as string, scope);

        var result = ValidationResult.Success;

        if (!isValid)
            result = new ValidationResult("The provided IP Address is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address");

        return result;
    }
}
```

And then can consume that from a route constraint:

```
public class IPAddressRouteConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint {
    public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object value;
        if (!values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value))
            return false;

        var attr = new IPAddressAttribute();

        return attr.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

This way it's shared as both in the route and at the model validation (depending where I need the logic).

Answer (score -1):

Should it get that far? Tried this...

```
[Route("api/stuff/{id:regex(^\d+-[a-z]{3}$)}")]
```

Comment: Clarified my question. I used `RegularExpressionAttribute` as it was the simplest, but it could be any validation attribute (range, data type, something custom)